# How to delete UIImage from UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

How to delete UIImage from UIImageView ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just set view's image property to nil:

```
yourImageView.image = nil;
```

Comment: i assume that yourImageView.image = nil; uses autorelease , but i want to release memory now , not waiting autorelease

Comment: no, it must send release message to the image, so if image was not retained somewhere else (e.g. cached if it was created with +imageName method) it should get deallocated

Comment: yes, you are right , i will change imageName to imageWithContentsOfFile

Comment: @Vladimir : I used that line in my code..But all get is image overlapped on previous one..Can you please help me?? I have searched a lot for this question and I've got same answer from everywhere.. :-((

Comment: @patel.rohn you must have something else wrong, may be several instances of image view or something else - post some code (better as a separate question)

Comment: @Vladimir: I do neither want to hijack this post nor want to ask question which may closed because of "POSSIBLE DUPLICATE"..So please just look these to images..I am having overlapping problem..Still if you suggest to post new question I will do..
 Before:  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/338/screenshot20111104at112.png/

After: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/screenshot20111104at112.png/

Comment: @patel.rohn can't say anything without seeing the code. better post it as separate question

Answer (score 0):

Setting the image property to nil should achieve this, I'd have thought.

See the full image property method signature within the U[IImageView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs.